# Error - For all subdirectories under a main dir - create a list of files within each subdirectory

Tags: perl

I am trying to generate individual list of files inside each subdirectory under one given directory. This may be an already addressed and resolved problem, but my specific issue is that my sub directories will always have a pattern in name and also have exact number files for eg -

```
 <**Main_Dir**>

<sub-directory>- sub1_dir with files 
    sub1.name.txt
    sub1.place.txt
    sub3.time.txt
    sub4.date.txt

<sub-directory>- sub2_dir with files 
    sub2.name.txt
    sub2.place.txt
   ..............

<sub-directory>- sub3_dir with files 
        sub3.name.txt
       ...............
       .......
```

Is there a way to make the code loop over each sub* subfolder, since I know the pattern/name for these main folders will remain like this? 
In short the script should create a file under each subdirectory with list of files in it.

Eg -

```
<sub-directory>- sub1_dir with files 
        List_sub1_dir.txt
        sub1.name.txt
       ..............
<sub-directory>- sub2_dir with files 
        List_sub2_dir.txt
      ...............
```

**My edited code** -  **It does not create any list file in the subfolder** Can someone please help me find the error? Thanks a lot!!

```
    use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule;
my $directory = './Maindir';

my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in( $directory );

foreach my $dir (@subdirs) {
        #print "$dir\n";
        next if ($dir eq "..");

        if (-d $dir)
        {
        my @files = File::Find::Rule->file() ->name( '*.*' ) ->in( $di
+r);

        foreach my $file (@files)
                {
        open (FH,"$file");


        while (<FH>)
        {
        open FILE,">>./$dir.txt" or die $!;
        print FILE "$_";
        }
        close(FH);
        close FILE;

        #print  "$file\n";

                }


        }
```

Comment: sounds like a job for [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
my @files = glob './Main_dir/*/*.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there anyway through which I can list the full path of the file, not just `./Main_dir/sub1_dir/sub1.name.txt?` for example, if user executes the script from ./Main_dir which is located in - /usr/bin/local/Main_dir, can the list of file look like /usr/bin/local/Main_dir/sub1_dir/sub1.name.txt? Thanks!

Comment: @B_perl: You could use `rel2abs` from `File::Spec::Functions`

Answer (score 0):

As someone else suggested, [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) is a useful module for this type of task.  Personally, I prefer to use [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) instead.  Basically File::Find:Rule provides an alternate interface to the File::Find module.

Here's an example using File::Find::Rule to find all files (with full paths) within a directory (and within it's subdirectories):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = '/mydir';
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new();
$rule->$file;
my @files = $rule->in($dir);

foreach my $file (@files) {say $file;}
```

UPDATE:

The above code has a typo.  The `$rule->$file;` line should be `$rule->file;`.

Comment: Thanks @dasgar - I tried this, but i am getting an error -` Use of uninitialized value in method lookup at list_file_v3.pl line 13.
Can't locate method File::Find::Rule:: at list_file_v3.pl line 13, which is `$rule-> $file`;. I tried the script after removing this line and it lists everything in the main directory ( including all subdirectories). How can I create a list within each subdirectory with just files inside it.

Comment: That's because I had a typo.  Change `$rule->$file;` to be `$rule->file;`.  I had an extra sigil that didn't belong.  I apologize for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works now, should i loop over each subdirectory inorder to create a list file within each subdirectory? As this results in one list with all files from all subdirectories. thanks!

Comment: Rather than trying to write the code for you, I was basically trying to share one module that could help you out.  If were to write the code for you, I would be asking for more details (what does the full file/directory - such as how many levels of subdirectories and are there subdirectories that need to be ignored, what are you trying to do with file list, etc.).  One route that you could do is to use File::Find::Rule to find the list of subdirectories.  Then loop over that list to find the files in each subdirectories.

Comment: yes dasgar, thanks for sharing the code, I am iterating over sub dirs using opener and reader and then using your code. I was just trying to use/seek a different approach of using pattern match for subfolder names like sub_dir1, sub_dir2.But, I will stick with this approach as it solves the purpose.

Comment: Hi @dasgar, I was able to run the script and create a list file for each subdirectory, but I have just one small error - My script reads the ./Maindir in the directory array as well, apart from all the subdirectories inside it. Is there a way to not read the ./Maindir in `File::Find::Rule->directory->in( $directory );` but all subsequent /.. directories? Thanks a lot!